# WebPICmdLine.exe not working on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am working on Windows Azure SDK 1.4 version. I have written an sample application having a startp script. Script is as below:

```
"%~dp0\WebPICmdLine.exe" /Products: WDeploy /xml:https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/2.0/RTM/WebProductList.xml /log:webdeploy.txt
net stop wmsvc
net start wmsvc
```

If application is deployed on Azure along with this script, webrole goes in busy and aborted state. If I remove this script and deploy an application, it works fine, without any error.

Is anyone faced this kind of issue or anyone has an idea about this issue? OR
anyone know how I can see log file `/log:webdeploy.txt` mentioned in command and where this file wil be located after deploying an application on Windows Azure?

Anykind of suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi
got the answer:
Please refer link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/49c6c7a3-313b-47bc-bda2-2c94e617bd80

To work command, we need to add paramerer `/accepteula` 
Now, if I run command as mentioned below, its working fine.

```
"%~dp0\WebPICmdLine.exe" /accepteula /Products: WDeploy /xml:https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/2.0/RTM/WebProductList.xml /log:webdeploy.txt
```

Comment: It would be nice if you included the actual resolution to the problem here, not just the link.